# Sqlite Insert return Id correct, but value in the field are missing

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this database:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_RISCALA = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_RISCALA
            + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
            + KEY_STORE_TIPO + " TEXT not null,"
            + KEY_STORE_NAME + " TEXT not null,"
            + KEY_RISC_TOT + " REAL,"
            + KEY_RISC_ING + " REAL,"
            + KEY_ING + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_FLAG + " INTEGER ,"
            + KEY_1 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_2 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_3 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_4 + " REAL,"
            + KEY_5 + " REAL,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
```

and the table is create correctly, when I insert the data inside I use this function:

```
public long insert_row_riscala(String tipo,String nome) {

        long id = 0;
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_STORE_TIPO, tipo);
        values.put(KEY_STORE_NAME, nome);
        values.put(KEY_RISC_TOT, "1000");
        values.put(KEY_RISC_ING, "1000");
        values.put(KEY_FLAG, "0");
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

        // insert row
        synchronized (dbLock) {
            //id = dbWrite.insert(TABLE_RISCALA, null, values);
            //id = dbWrite.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_RISCALA, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
            id = dbWrite.insertOrThrow(TABLE_RISCALA, null, values);
        }
        return id;
    }
```

If the value that insert are different all works fine, for example:

id (is autoincrement by database)

```
the value in the field KEY_STORE_TIPO is "Sorbetto"
the value in the field KEY_STORE_NAME is "Mora"
```

when I try to insert (add to database) new value for example:

id (is autoincrement by database)

```
the value in the field KEY_STORE_TIPO is "Granita"
the value in the field KEY_STORE_NAME is "Mora"
```

the return id is correctly ( > 0) but when I read the database by external program (DB Browser for SQLite) for verify the insert data, I found that therisn't second INSERT.
No Exception are generated!
How it possible?

**EDIT SOLVED**

Inside another thread I have another query

```
String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_RISCALA + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " NOT IN (SELECT MIN(" + KEY_ID + ") FROM " + TABLE_RISCALA +
                "  GROUP BY " + KEY_STORE_NAME + ")";
```

but I missing to insert KEY_STORE_TIPO!!
Final query to delete duplicates is:

```
String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_RISCALA + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " NOT IN (SELECT MIN(" + KEY_ID + ") FROM " + TABLE_RISCALA +
                "  GROUP BY " + KEY_STORE_TIPO + "," + KEY_STORE_NAME + ")";
```

Sorry!

Comment: I am not sure, but it looks like if the transaction in which insert is performed is not committed. Do you perform any transaction operations elsewhere?

Comment: no, single operation

Comment: Random thoughts: (http://sqlitebrowser.org/) Do refresh. Check the SQL Log for the actual query issued. See if you need to scroll the results. :)